# RSpec test link_to inside p tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rspec2

Is it possible to have a test for the following html structure?

```
<p class="all-jobs"><%= link_to "<< Back to all jobs", jobs_path %></p>
```

I tried doing it this way:

```
it { should have_selector('p.all-jobs', link: "<< Back to all jobs")}
```

The error is:

```
 1) JobPages visit a job page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('p.all-jobs', link: "<< Back to all jobs")}
   expected css "p.all-jobs" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/job_pages_spec.rb:78:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting from running the test? That should work as is. Are you sure you have the right subject? If not, be sure to have it as `page.should`

Comment: I have this at the top of the page:   subject { page }. this should now be referenced using 'it'

Comment: Then can you show the error message from running the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it to work with the following:

```
describe "should have a link to index page" do
  it { should have_selector('a', title: "<< Back to all jobs", href: jobs_path) }
end
```

Comment: If you're not testing for a link inside a paragraph but just the existence of the link itself, perhaps `it { should have_link("<< Back to all jobs", href: jobs_path) }` will suffice.

Comment: i get this error when using have_link: JobPages visit a job page should have a link to index page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_link("<< Back to all jobs", href: jobs_path) }
       expected link "<< Back to all jobs" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/job_pages_spec.rb:80:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'